# Best way to close async resteasy client call

Tags: resteasy, quarkus

I have the following code:

```
var threadsWaiter = new CountDownLatch(customers.size());
for(var c: List<Customer> customers) {
   sendSms(c.phoneNr, threadsWaiter)
}
threadsWaiter.await();

public void sendSms(String phoneNr, CountDownLatch threadsWaiter) {
  ResteasyClientBuilder.newClient()
            .target(smsUrl)                
            .queryParam("to", phoneNr)
            .queryParam("message", message)
            .request()
            .async()
            .get(new InvocationCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void completed(String res) {
                    threadsWaiter.countDown();
                    if (res != null && !res.contains("code=ok") {
                        logger.error("Received sms response for '{}'\n{}", phoneNr, res);
                    } else {                            
                        logger.debug("Sms sent to '{}'", phoneNr);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
                    threadsWaiter.countDown();
                    logger.error("Error sending sms for {}: \n{}", phoneNr, throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
}
```

And I get the following warning from the console:

> `RESTEASY004687: Closing a class org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient43Engine instance for you. Please close clients yourself.`

What is the proper way to close this client call? Because this might be a source for a potential memory leak in the application. And even I get this warning from RestEasy that it closes the client automatically for me, but I've a strong feeling that it doesn't close all the clients since I see a huge memory increase in the metrics and this doesn't "go down" after a while.

I've placed the rest client call between try-finally, but the problem with this is that you can close the client before the call is finished. Is it ok to close the client in the `completed(..)` and the `failed(..)` methods in the InvocationCallback or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this with Quarkus would be to use the [REST client with async support](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client#async-support). **Example:**

```java
    /**
     * This is the client stub.
     */
    @Path("/sms/response") // base URL is set in application.yml
    @RegisterRestClient
    public interface SmsServiceClient {
        
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        CompletionStage<String> sendSms(
            @QueryParam("to") String phoneNr,
            @QueryParam("message") String message);
    }
```

In the following example, I'm using [SmallRye Mutiny](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny) to convert the `CompletionStage` into a `Uni` which has a leaner API. But you can achieve the same using the `CompletionStage`. Normally, I would not block the execution with that `CountDownLatch.await()` method. I stuck it in there to keep the code similar to your example.

```java
    /**
     * This class will actually use the client.
     */
    @Slf4J
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class MySomething {
        
        @Inject
        @RestClient
        SmsServiceClient smsClient;

        public void sendSmsInLoop() {
            var waiter = new CountDownLatch(customers.size());
            customers.forEach(customer -> {
                Uni.createFrom().completionStage(
                    smsClient.sendSms(customer.getPhoneNr(), "Lorem Ipsum...")
                ).onItem().invoke(responseString -> {
                    if (responseString == null || !responseString.contains("code=ok")) {
                        log.error("Unexpected sms response for '{}'\n{}", customer.getPhoneNr(), responseString); 
                    } else {
                        log.debug("Sms sent to '{}'", customer.getPhoneNr());
                    }
                }).onFailure().invoke(throwable -> {
                    log.error("Error sending sms to '{}'\n{}", customer.getPhoneNr(), throwable.getMessage());
                }).eventually(() -> waiter.countDown());
            });
            waiter.await();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the client definition via JaxRS interface is ok for you, then the answer from [rowing-goul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405613/rowing-ghoul) above is the way to go. Injected clients are automatically closed by Quarkus Arc during bean destroyer process. If you create clients manually, then you must close them explicitly - best way is `try - finally`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's not Quarkus, but I can close it manually.

```java
try {
    client.call(); 
    .... // it was injected before so I cannot use try-with-resources
} catch (Exception e) {
    ....
} finally {
    client.close();
}
```